# Error while using `find_or_create_by` on a `has_many` `through` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I am running in to a problem while using `find_or_create_by` on a `has_many`  `through` association.

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB columns: user_id, role_id

  has_many :permissions
  has_many :users, :through => :permissions
end

class User
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :roles, :through => :permissions
end
```

Rails throws an error when I invoke `find_or_create_by` on `roles` association of a `User` object.

```
u = User.first
u.roles.find_or_create_by_rolename("admin")

# Rails throws the following error
# NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id=' for #<Role id: nil, rolename: nil, 
#  created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I was able to work around the problem by changing my code as follows:

```
unless u.roles.exists?(:rolename => "admin")
  u.roles << Role.find_or_create_by_rolename("admin") 
end
```

I am curious to find if `find_or_create_by` works with `has_many` `through` associations.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but not with `:through`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is confined to :through. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I don't think that you will get any more answers on this one. The `find_or_...` methods aren't supposed to work with the `:through` associations.
The only way you could get it working would be by deleting the `Permission` model and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with a simple mapping-table.

Comment: Calls such as `u.roles.find_by_rolename("admin")` works with `has_many :through`. So I thought `u.roles.find_or_create_by_rolename("admin")` might work. Can you point me to the documentation where this caveat is specified?

Comment: I would be happy to prove this issue, but the find_by-methods aren't documented very well.
However I think it's easy to understand why the "create" part does not work (while "find" does): The create would need to guess/generate a mapping "Permission". Rails can do this with `habtm` but not with complex types (what if you have validators in Permissions? You would be pretty screwed.)

Comment: The `create` call like `u.roles.create(:rolename => "admin")` works. Rails creates the `Permission` map automatically. I expected `find_or_create` to work similarly(assuming that there is no validation errors). At this stage I am curious to know if it is a conscious omission OR a bug.