# How to check if a record exists before creating a new one in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Heres what I'm trying to accomplish:

- I have a tagging system in place.
- Tags are created, when Posts are created (posts has_many :tags, :through => :tag_joins.
- A tag join is automatically created when a post is created with tags).

I want to check if the tag already exists. If it does I want to use the existing tag for the tag_join record, rather than creating a new tag record.

Here is my current code, which isn't working.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag_join
  belongs_to :post

  before_create :check_exists

  def check_exists
    tag = Tag.where(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id)
    if tag.nil?
      tag = Tag.create(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id)
    end
  end

end
```

This doesn't work though, I'm getting an error upon task creation...(the server is actually just timing out - I don't receive a specific error).

Any ideas?

Tokland said I was creating an infinite loop by telling it to create tag again - so I tried this:

```
 def check_exists
      tag = Tag.find_by_name_and_user_id(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id)
      if tag != nil
        self.id = tag.id
      end
  end
```

And still get the server timeout

Edit: I'm not sure if this matters, but the way the tags are being added is similar to "http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

they're nested in the post form, and use something like this:

```
def tag_attributes=(tag_attributes)
  tag_attributes.each do |attributes|
    tags.build(attributes)
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if this is stopping this whole thing from working? Also, using current_user.id in the model definitely seems to be an issue...

**EDIT:**

Something I have figured out:
 this had to change, the format we were using before was incorrect syntax - generally used for a .where method.

```
  def check_exists
     @tag = Tag.find_by_name_and_user_id(self.name, self.user_id) 
     if @tag != nil
       #return false
       #self=@tag
     end
  end
```

The problem now is this, I can learn if it the tag already exists. But then what? If I go with the return false option, there is an error upon post creation, and the join record isn't created... The other option "self=@tag" obviously just doesn't work.

Comment: Code review time: When naming routines, you want to use a name that is indicative of what it does. Calling a method "check_exists" when it could actually be creating records could make it harder to find "where'd that record come from?" once you've got a lot of code in an app. Maybe "get_tag" or "find_or_create_tag" would be better? Subtle things like this add up in an app and determine its readability and maintainability over time.

Comment: The server timeout is probably not related to the code. Check to see whether it's actually running, and, if it's on another machine, whether you have connectivity to it.

Comment: Its actually just happening in my local environment. The server freezes up everytime I try to create a tag even manually through rails admin.

Comment: Your server is freezing because you are creating on a before_create! infinite loop...

Comment: I just tried new code that shouldn't have an infinite loop.. but same error

Comment: @Elliot. What is this new code? anyway, you are using before_creating the wrong way, remove completely the callback and use  find_or_create_by as suggested. Or the pattern: tag = Tag.find(...) || Tag.create!(...)

Comment: @Elliot why don't you edit you previous post with the same question instead of creating another one [Using before_create in rails3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976840/using-before-create-in-rails3)

Comment: @artshayderov because I'm starting to think before_create isn't the way to go..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're going to find it hard to to this from within the Tag model. It seems like what you want is to update the Post using nested attributes, like so:

```
post = Post.create
post.update_attributes(:tags_attributes=>{"0"=>{:name=>"fish",:user_id=>"37"}})
```

This is actually pretty simple to do by using a virtual attribute setter method:

```
class Post < AR::Base
  has_many :tags

  def tags_attributes=(hash)
    hash.each do |sequence,tag_values|
      tags <<  Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(tag_values[:name],\
        tag_values[:user_id])
    end
  end

> post = Post.create
> post.update_attributes(:tags_attributes=>{"0"=>{:name=>"fish",:user_id=>"37"}})
> Tag.count # => 1
# updating again does not add dups
> post.update_attributes(:tags_attributes=>{"0"=>{:name=>"fish",:user_id=>"37"}})
> Tag.count # => 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much Zetetic, I was struggling all day!

Comment: I found this after 5 hours of searching, you're my hero

Answer (score 9):

There's a `find_or_create_by_` function built right in to Rails

```
# No 'Summer' tag exists
Tag.find_or_create_by_name("Summer") # equal to Tag.create(:name => "Summer")

# Now the 'Summer' tag does exist
Tag.find_or_create_by_name("Summer") # equal to Tag.find_by_name("Summer")
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html (under Dynamic attribute-based finders)

Comment: How can I use this if I'm checking based on name and user_id though? And where should I use this? In the check_exists method?

Comment: Yes, see Rob Di Marco has provided a simple example, see below.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the magic method `find_or_create_by`

```
def check_exists
    tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Check out the [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) docs for more info

Comment: getting a server timeout using this

Comment: The problem is that the check_exists method is run as a before_create call, but it is itself trying to create the Tag.  So if you want to use the Tag.find_or_create_by_name_and_user_id, you should do that from the calling code (your controller maybe?).  If you are trying to enforce that the tag only shows up once with the name/user id combination, check out validates_uniqueness_of which will ensure this.

Comment: Hey Rob, that makes sense - I just updated the question. The way the tags are being created seems kind of complicated (used a railscast ep - as linked above), I'm wondering if I should be using the find_or_create in the method I added above?

Answer (score 5):

The question I originally asked got pretty distorted by the end. So I'm separating it.

People who are trying to do what I originally asked can try this:

```
 before_create :check_tag_exists

 private

 def check_tag_exists
     @tag = Tag.find_by_name_and_user_id(self.name, self.user_id)
     if @tag != nil
       #
     end
  end
```

This will enable you to check if your record has already been created. Any further logic you can drop in that if statment.

Comment: Good deal coming back to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the other answers are a bit dated. Here's how you should probably accomplish this for Rails 4

```
tag = Tag.first_or_initialize(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id)
if !tag.new_record?
    tag.id = self.id
    tag.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  def check_exists
    tag = Tag.where(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id).first
    tag = Tag.new({:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id}) unless tag
  end
```

use `Tag.new` instead of `Tag.create`

Comment: Tag.where will return collection, you can use 
``Tag.where(:name => self.name, :user_id => current_user.id).first``

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just copy pasted that part from the question and did not check that line. will make the edit.

Answer (score -2):

where returns an empty ActiveRecord on finding no match.