# RoR - check if record exist before build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have two models

```
Address.rb
  belongs_to :zip
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :zip

Zip.rb
  has_many :addresses
```

on the form for a new Address I also create a Zip. But i want to check if the inserted Zip already exists. If it does it should return the existing Zip, if it doesn't it should create a new one

```
AddressController
  def new
    @address = Address.new
    @address.build_zip
  end
```

I saw on StackOverFlow a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978893/how-to-check-if-a-record-exists-before-creating-a-new-one-in-rails3) without the answer I was hopping for... Someone suggested:

```
  before_create :check_zip_exists

  def check_zip_exists
    @zip = Zip.find_by_cp1_and_cp2(self.cp1, self.cp2)
    if @zip!=nil
      #
    end
  end
```

what should be at `#` in order to associate the existing Zip to the Address instead creating a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord Create or Find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905038/rails-activerecord-create-or-find)

Comment: http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the one you indicate. As I said in my question, its a duplicate of another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978893/how-to-check-if-a-record-exists-before-creating-a-new-one-in-rails3) that does not have a complete answer, that's why I'm asking again

Comment: Yes, it's a dupe of that one, too. And probably about 50 others... `@address.zip = Zip.find_or_create_by...`

Comment: It's not a dupe because none of that questions as an answer that works. You can check it if you want... `find_or_create_by` won't work because I want to find based on two arguments and creating with 6 arguments... But thanks for you participation

Comment: That information is not anywhere in your question. FWIW find_or_create_by takes a variable number of arguments. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by (this same link is in the answer of the linked question, BTW). It is also addressed in several of the answers in the link you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this was arranged like this:

```
Address.rb
  belongs_to :zip
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :zip, :reject_if => :check_zip_exists

  private

  def check_zip_exists(attributed)
    cp1 = attributed['cp1']
    cp2 = attributed['cp2']
    zip = Zip.where(:cp1=>cp1, :cp2=>cp2).first
    if zip.nil?
      return false
    else
      self.zip_id = zip.id
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
zip = Zip.where(field: value).first_or_create
```

**Update**

When you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :zip` what happens inside is that a public method called `zip_attributes=(attributes)` is generated.

This method, calls a private method (depending if relation is a collection or a single object), in your case the private method called is `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association`

So you can override the public_method `zip_attributes=(attributes)` in your `Address` model to replace the normal behavior:

```
def zip_attributes=(attributes)
  self.zip = Zip.where(attributes).first_or_create #you can change attributes to be the fields that you need to find the correct zip
end
```

**Update 2**

```
def zip_attributes=(attributes)
  cp1 = attributes.delete(:cp1)
  cp2 = attributes.delete(:cp2)
  self.zip = Zip.where(cp1: cp1, cp2: cp2).first_or_create(attributes)
end
```

Comment: will that return the existing Zip instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Yes it will return the existing Zip

Comment: and where should I put that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I didn't managed to make it work like that because I need to find based on two attributes (:cp1 and :cp2) but if it doesn't exist I need to create with 6 attributes (:cp1, :cp2, and others...)

Comment: Ok, I've updated one more time my answer, give a look.